# Is this email from Liliane Bettencourt a scam?

Tags: email, spam

I received the following email from someone claiming to be the second-richest woman in the world, *Liliane Bettencourt*.

> I, Liliane authenticate this email, you can read about me on: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liliane_Bettencourt I write to you because I intend to give you a portion of my Net-worth which I have been banking. I want to cede it out as gift hoping it would be of help to you and others too. Respond for confirmation.
>
> With love,
>   Liliane H Bettencourt

Is it genuine, or a known scam?

Comment: It's **obviously** spam, but [I need some references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Liliane_Bettencourt#Addition_of_.27Liliane_Bettencourt_email_scam.27_article) backing up that claim for Wikipedia.

Comment: Wait, you know it's a scam, but you want to know if it is a scam??

Comment: @IQAndreas You are fighting against windmills. Those scammers aren't stupid. When you get that warning added to that wikipedia article, they just pick some other billionaire instead.

Comment: @Philipp "Tilting at windmills" :)

Comment: If you believe that, I have a bank account belonging to one <John Smith> who died in a car crash, which I urgently need to transfer out of a bank ;p

Comment: @Philipp Obviously, you don't know much about adventures. ([source](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/90626-destiny-guides-our-fortunes-more-favorably-than-we-could-have))

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is a scam.   Any email you get, from anyone you don't know, offering you money, is a scam.  This is a rule of thumb that is essentially 100% accurate 100% of the time.

The best course of action to take, when you receive emails like this, is to delete them as soon as you identify them, in order to minimize the amount of time you waste reading them.

Comment: And mails from those you do know with genuine offers of money are exceedingly rare.